# Need SQL query | SQL 10g | Orace

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

My parent table is as below :

```
Date        Month   PRICE   product contract_month  Contract_year
7-Jun-17    17-Sep  -79     XYZ     9                2017
7-Jun-17    17-Oct  -75     XYZ     10               2017
7-Jun-17    17-Jul  -92     XYZ     7                2017
7-Jun-17    17-Aug  -90     XYZ     8                2017
7-Jun-17    18-Sep  -95     XYZ     9                2018
7-Jun-17    18-Oct  -96     XYZ     10               2018
7-Jun-17    18-Nov  -97     XYZ     11               2018
```

Am executing below query :

```
SELECT opr_date,contract,price
                 FROM   table
                 WHERE  date = '07-jun-2017' 
                        AND product = 'XYZ'
                        ANd contract_year = 2017
                        AND contract_month between 1 and 12
```

My query is pulling out this result:

```
Date        Month   PRICE
7-Jun-17    17-Sep  -79
7-Jun-17    17-Oct  -75
7-Jun-17    17-Jul  -92
7-Jun-17    17-Aug  -90
```

But it should populate the price if and only if all three months in the quarter are present.
in the above ex: we have prices for jun July and Aug. So prices are present for all 3 month in 3rd quarter. So it should populate the respective price.
But for 4th quarter i.e for month Oct,Nov and dec (contract_month = 10,11 &12) , only oct price is present. So my query should not populate this price or it should populate as null (since price is not present for nov and dec in parent table).

Answer (score 1):

Determine the quarter by year and count the results (group by, having count=3):

```
select opr_date,contract,price
  from your_table
 where /* your conditions ...   */
     date = '07-jun-2017'
 and product = 'XYZ'
 and contract_year = 2017
 and contract_month between 1 and 12
/* only rows, where exist 3 rows per quarter */
 and case
   when contract_month between 1 and 3 then
    contract_year * 10 + 1
   when contract_month between 4 and 6 then
    contract_year * 10 + 2
   when contract_month between 7 and 9 then
    contract_year * 10 + 3
   else
    contract_year * 10 + 4
 end in (select quarter
           from (select case
                          when contract_month between 1 and 3 then
                           contract_year * 10 + 1
                          when contract_month between 4 and 6 then
                           contract_year * 10 + 2
                          when contract_month between 7 and 9 then
                           contract_year * 10 + 3
                          else
                           contract_year * 10 + 4
                        end as quarter
                   from your_table)
          group by quarter
         having count(*) = 3);
```

Comment: Thanks Frank Ockenfuss !!